# Where could I find a partner to outsource defining photo clipping path?

Tags: photoshop, business

I know how to cut out images in Photoshop CS5 myself. But I think it's a perfect job to Outsource to get more time to other stuff. But where to turn? Any recomendations?

I estimate that there only will be about 10 images per project. And only a few projects per month.

I will deliver files in RAW format. Often with white background.

I want the images back as PSD files with all clipping paths, so I easily can correct mistakes myself.

Comment: What do you mean "photo clipping path" or "cut out images"? I'm not sure what task you are trying to actually get outsourced. Also, it seems that this is strictly about Photoshop and processing, it might fit better on the graphic design stack exchange site.

Comment: @dpollitt - I'm not sure this is all that appropriate for that site either...

Comment: JoanneC: Yea, I think outsourcing photo editing is something very common of professional photographers - so maybe it is on topic here even? Maybe the way it is being asked isn't very relevant though.

Comment: Thanks for making my question more clear :) I have found a few compnaies that I will try out. I will get back with my results, but please give me tips if you have any. It would be interested to get intouch with a photoshop freelancer in India.

Comment: Possibly of interest: http://www.pixiq.com/article/why-how-to-outsource-portrait-retouching-drudgery

Answer (score 1):

You could try Amazon's [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/).  I've heard of it used for things like proof-reading manuscripts. I'll bet you can get any repetitive task like this done.